# Stored Procedure Error on Commit and Begin Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

**ERROR**

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

I get this error in my Stored Procedure that I cannot see where.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpsertServiceTicket]
    @TransactionType INT,
    @Id INT = NULL,
    @CreationDateTime DATETIME = GETDATE,
    @Issue VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReportedDateTime DATETIME = NULL,
    @ResolutinoDateTime DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedBy INT = NULL,
    @ServiceRequestNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Status VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @IsDeleted BIT = 0,
    @LocationId INT,
    @SubLocationId INT,
    @RequestorId INT,
    @ConfirmedBy INT = NULL,
    @DepartmentId INT,
    @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
    @ErrorCode SMALLINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            IF (@TransactionType = 0)
                INSERT INTO ServiceTickets (
                    CreationDateTime
                    , Issue 
                    , ReportedDateTime
                    , ResolutionDateTime
                    , CreatedBy
                    , ServiceRequestNumber
                    , [Status]
                    , IsDeleted
                    , LocationId
                    , SubLocationId
                    , RequestorId
                    , ConfirmerId
                    , DepartmentId
                    )
                VALUES (
                    @CreationDateTime
                    , @Issue
                    , @ReportedDateTime
                    , @ResolutinoDateTime
                    , @CreatedBy
                    , @ServiceRequestNumber
                    , @Status
                    , @IsDeleted
                    , @LocationId
                    , @SubLocationId
                    , @RequestorId
                    , @ConfirmedBy
                    , @DepartmentId
                )
        -- updating the service ticket table
            ELSE
                UPDATE      ServiceTickets
                SET         CreationDateTime        = @CreationDateTime
                            , Issue                 = @Issue
                            , ReportedDateTime      = @ReportedDateTime
                            , ResolutionDateTime    = @ResolutinoDateTime
                            , CreatedBy             = @CreatedBy
                            , ServiceRequestNumber  = @ServiceRequestNumber
                            , [Status]              = @Status
                            , IsDeleted             = @IsDeleted
                            , LocationId            = @LocationId
                            , SubLocationId         = @SubLocationId
                            , RequestorId           = @RequestorId
                            , ConfirmerId           = ConfirmerId
                            , DepartmentId          = DepartmentId
                WHERE Id = @Id
 
            SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            SET @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
            IF (@ErrorCode = 0)
                COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrorCode = @@ERROR;
  
        IF @ErrorCode > 0
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is almost always your friend, as is adhering to a certain pattern for error handling, which always involves checking `@@TRANCOUNT` to know if we should rollback or not. See, e.g., [here](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html#commonpatterns) (the whole article series is a good read if you want to get the nitty gritty of T-SQL error handling).

Comment: Do note that the use of a transaction here is completely unnecessary, because your sproc only ever executes a single DML statement (the `IF` doesn't count). Single statements implicitly happen in their own transaction if none has been explicitly started, so there is no point to you checking the outcome and committing or rolling back -- the engine does that for you. Removing the transaction and `TRY .. CATCH` entirely will not make the code any less robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
Begin Tran <TransactionName>

BEGIN TRY
   --Some Statements
   Commit Tran <TransactionName>
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Error NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @Error = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK TRAN <TransactionName>
    RAISERROR (@Error, 16, 1)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling code is incorrect, as it does not rollback or commit the transaction in certain cases

It also swallows exceptions and instead returns an error code. You are far better off just letting the error bubble up back to the client. You should use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to ensure a rollback.

Given that you are only ever executing one statement, you don't even need a transaction anyway

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpsertServiceTicket]
    @TransactionType INT,
    @Id INT = NULL,
    @CreationDateTime DATETIME = NULL,
    @Issue VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReportedDateTime DATETIME = NULL,
    @ResolutinoDateTime DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedBy INT = NULL,
    @ServiceRequestNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Status VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @IsDeleted BIT = 0,
    @LocationId INT,
    @SubLocationId INT,
    @RequestorId INT,
    @ConfirmedBy INT = NULL,
    @DepartmentId INT
AS

    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    SET @CreationDateTime = ISNULL(@CreationDateTime, GETDATE());

    IF (@TransactionType = 0)
        INSERT INTO ServiceTickets (
                    CreationDateTime
                    , Issue 
                    , ReportedDateTime
                    , ResolutionDateTime
                    , CreatedBy
                    , ServiceRequestNumber
                    , [Status]
                    , IsDeleted
                    , LocationId
                    , SubLocationId
                    , RequestorId
                    , ConfirmerId
                    , DepartmentId
                    )
                VALUES (
                    @CreationDateTime
                    , @Issue
                    , @ReportedDateTime
                    , @ResolutinoDateTime
                    , @CreatedBy
                    , @ServiceRequestNumber
                    , @Status
                    , @IsDeleted
                    , @LocationId
                    , @SubLocationId
                    , @RequestorId
                    , @ConfirmedBy
                    , @DepartmentId
                );
        -- updating the service ticket table
        ELSE
            UPDATE      ServiceTickets
                SET         CreationDateTime        = @CreationDateTime
                            , Issue                 = @Issue
                            , ReportedDateTime      = @ReportedDateTime
                            , ResolutionDateTime    = @ResolutinoDateTime
                            , CreatedBy             = @CreatedBy
                            , ServiceRequestNumber  = @ServiceRequestNumber
                            , [Status]              = @Status
                            , IsDeleted             = @IsDeleted
                            , LocationId            = @LocationId
                            , SubLocationId         = @SubLocationId
                            , RequestorId           = @RequestorId
                            , ConfirmerId           = ConfirmerId
                            , DepartmentId          = DepartmentId
                WHERE Id = @Id;
```

If you do need a transaction to do a proper Upsert, use [this template](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern), with `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK` hints. You do not need a `BEGIN CATCH` as `XACT_ABORT ON` will handle the rollback